# Quick Good Rules of Thumb to decide to create a new function or create a new class in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, methods, standards

I'm not sure if stackoverflow is the place to ask for advice on general principles, so let me know if not, but here it is:

1. What are good rules of thumb in deciding whether to create a new class for a function or just add the function to the current class?
2. What are good rules of thumb in deciding whether to create a new function that takes the data from the previous function or just continue the old function?

I'm starting to read up on Object Oriented Programming, but are there any quick good rules of thumb you could share?

Background: 
I'm learning python to pull data via API, manipulate it, and send an email report. Since, it's just a long script (though about 2,000 lines now), I could theoretically make one long function.

Even though I divide it into modular chunks for the purposes of readability and ease of building, I arbitrarily decide how long a function should be or how many functions should be contained within a class. I often ask myself if I should just make my function longer or should I make my functions as short as possible or whether I should make a new class for a new function. I see functions and classes as a form of categorization, so I think I'm missing some fundamental concept about object-oriented programming in general.

I'm also conflicted on whether I should lean towards concise names or specific names. The former tends to be more ambiguous and the latter tends to make the names to long, which is annoying when referring to them. Obviously, going for balance, but should I lean towards one direction more than the other.

Comment: Might be a better fit on http://programmers.stackexchange.com, and it certainly isn't unique to Python

Comment: If you read an OOP book you will get this in a minute (maybe not a minute, but with a better and more detailed explanation).

Comment: Good advice! Will do!

Comment: One rule of thumb is to have code modularized enough that you can see a whole function on the screen.

Comment: Something I can tell you, is that a function should do a specific task, so every small task you have, it should be a function. (Of course this also depends on context). You could divide your "long" function into smaller tasks. Something I read and found interesting, was that if you **can't** give a descriptive and representative *name* to a function, maybe that function is too general and you should divide it into smaller functions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's true to a certain extent, but the decision whether or not to put things in a class will differ across languages. In Java, for example, everything must be in a class: that's not the case in Python, which has standalone functions, so classes should only really be used where you're encapsulating data.